# Vue2 JS - v-for component in a form

Tags: vuejs2

i'm facing this problem.

I have a form where i get a component with a v-for cycle.
In this component I have a multiple select.

I cannot understand how to gather data from the components when submitting the form

I modified the question thanks to @Reinier68 tip on Components, bu still not getting

This is my component

```
<template>
<div>
  <select
     v-bind:value="selectedValue"
  v-on:select="$emit('select', $event.target.selectedValue)"
   :options="options"></select>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: 'categorySelect',
data: function(){
    return {
        selected: []
    }
},
props: {

    options: Array,
    selectedValue: null
},

}
</script>
```

Then, in the parent, i use this component in a v-for

```
<div v-for="cu in s.cus" :key="cu.cuId">

    <category-select :options="options" v-model="selected[cu.cuId]" :selectedValue="value"></category-select>
</div>
```

The problem is that when submitting the for i still get nothing, my `selected[]` is null

Comment: Don't know if you made a typo, but it should be `@selected="selected[cu.cuId]"` and not `selected="selected[cu.cuId]"`.

Comment: thanks, it was a typo, it was a v-model to bind it

Comment: You should read this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components, cuz the way you're trying to use v-model with props won't work.

Comment: `$emit('select',` emits a `@select` event to the caller, where are you adding that to `<category-select/>`?

Comment: i just need to bind the selected option to the parent v-model on component call

Answer (score 0):

`props` are for input, `$emit` is for output.

You pass in the value into the component with the prop, then on change, you use `$emit` to send the value out, then listen for the value on the component.

To assign back the selected value it's better to use a method but can be achived inline `@select="v => $set(values, index, v)"` and because its an array you need to use $set else it wont be reactive like `@select="v => values[index] = v"`

Below is an example, not using an object as you have not provided it, but; it would be the same prop in, emit out.

```js
const categorySelect = {
  template: '#category-select',
  props: ['selected', 'options'],
  data() {
    return {
      value: this.selected
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      this.$emit('select', event.target.value)
    }
  }
}

//
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    categorySelect
  },
  data() {
    return {
      options: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      values: [1, 0, 5, 0]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- -->
  <div v-for="(value, index) in values" :key="index">
    <category-select 
      :options="options" 
      :selected="value" 
      @select="v => $set(values, index, parseInt(v, 10))"
    />
  </div>

  <!-- -->
  <pre>{{ values }}</pre>
</div>

<template id="category-select">
  <select 
    v-model="value"
    @change="onChange">
    <option v-for="option in options">{{option}}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```